# Class based view that inherits from a custom class based view does not see context variables in parent

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have written a Class based view which acts as a base view for several other class based views. So the other class based views is just subclassing the base view, but the subclassed views are not getting the effect of the get_context_data or form_valid functions, so the context variables set in the base view is not getting sent to the template when requests are executing using the view subclassing the base view, they are only being sent when the base view itself it used.

Class based view:

```
class PortfolioNewBase(CreateView):
    url_name = ''
    post_req = False

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.post_req = True
        return super(PortfolioNewBase, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PortfolioNewBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profile_id'] = self.kwargs['profile_id']
        context['post_req'] = self.post_req
        return super(PortfolioNewBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(self.url_name, args=self.kwargs['profile_id'])
```

When creating a new class based view which is one of the views that will be using this code it does not get access to the "profile_id" or "post_req" variables for some reason, it does not get sent to the template, but if you only use the base view written above that view will send the variables so that they are available in the view.

Code for one of the class based views using this base view written above:

```
class PortfolioNewDividend(PortfolioNewBase):
    model = Dividend
    form_class = DividendForm
    template_name = 'plan/portfolio/new/new_dividend.html'
    url_name = 'plan:investment-info-dividends-new'
```

The form works and everything, but the variables in the get_context_data in the parent is apparently not being inherited for some reason which is kind of the point here and the form_valid function is not being run either, the value of the post_req on POST requests done by the PortfolioNewDividend class based view still has the value False.

Why is the PortfolioNewDividend not running the get_context_data and form_valid functions when a request is executed with that view but the functions run if you use the base clase (written above) only ?

Comment: That `get_context_data` wouldn't work at all, either with the base class or the children, because you never return `context` but instead call `super` again and return that.

Comment: You&#39;re supposed to return the updated context. What you returned is the original context, unchanged.
The last line of `get_context_data` method should be `return context`

Comment: Ah yes, good point, that worked..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `super` call too many in there. Change as follows:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PortfolioNewBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['profile_id'] = self.kwargs['profile_id']
    context['post_req'] = self.post_req
    return context  # You must actually return the modified context!
```